# How to deal with Dependencies in MicroServices - Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, dependencies, microservices

I want to code three separate Micro-services **"CustomerMicroService"**, **"CartMicroService"** and **"OrderMicroService"** and later on I want to connect them via Spring Cloud (Broker Pattern and Service Discovery Pattern). But I already run into another problem: The Dependencies of each others MicroService.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int customerId;

    private String name;
    private String address;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CART_ID")
    private Cart cart

    @ElementaryCollection
    private Map<Integer, Order> orders;


    public Customer(Cart cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }
```

This example would work, if I would copy the classes of the other Micro-service into the one. But now I would just get a lot of Exceptions, because if I want to execute only one Micro-service, Spring Data JPA would not be able to find the Class of another Micro-service. How can I deal with that?

Comment: Imho, your service is not properly segregated. A microservice should be self-contained, i.e. if a `Customer` is not functional without a `Cart`, then they belong to the same microservice. If you, however, need only some information of your `Customer` in an `Order`, then the `Order` microservice should hold this data redundantly from the `Customer` service.

Comment: @Turing85 but I think it would not be a "Shop" of MicroServices at the end, when Customer and Cart are in one MicroService?

Comment: I did not say that they should be in one microservice. I just said that they should be if they need to be tightly coupled. The name `Customer` seems off to me already. It should be something like `User` (i.e. it holds more information, like an authentication method, a nick, a real name, email, postal address,...). This alone could at least be two services (the actual user service and an authenticatoin service, mapping at least one authentication method to each user). Then, the cart service only saves/replicates the user information it needs.

Comment: @Turing85 would it be a solution in your opinion, if I would only store the cartId as an variable and as a foreign key?

Comment: Quick question: do you use a single database service for all microservices?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, for now I'm using an hibernate Database. Later on I think, all MicroService are sharing a database.

Comment: Well then you are implementing more of a SOA and not a microservice. Since microservices should be self-contained, each microservice should use its own database to reduce coupling between the services... Anyhow. In my opinion (please regard it as such - there is no silver bullet here), the customer service is not responsible for the customer-to-card relation. This is the responsibility of the cart service. Thus, you need only to define the relationship on the `Cart` POJO.

Comment: @Turing85 -  Okay, I understand. You say "you only need to define the relationship to cart" -  But wouldn't this be, as you say more SOA and not a microservice attribute? 

It sounds like, if I have a MicroService, I should completely remove the relation to the cart?

Comment: No. If you were to implement it as microservice, the customer microservice would have its database and the cart service would have its database. If a new customer is registered (this is the responsibility of the customer service), the information of the new customer would be downstreamed on dependent services, e.g. the cart service. The cart service stores the relevant information (e.g. name, address, payment information) in its local database, aswell as the relationship to a cart (if one exists).